electron-builder nsis installer have missing data
I am trying build nsis installer for my electron application using following build code, i creates executable file/project perfectly. The total project size is ~13gb (because it have python executables as well which runs as electron sub process). but the msis installer have only ~1.3GB size, and after installation, it only have one unistall file, and nothing else, no executable file nothing... The windows add/remove app showing 8.3gb installation, but not sure where are they.
 "build": {
        "appId": "ABC.AI-ai",
        "dmg": {
            "title": "${productName} ${version}"
        },
        "win": {
            "target": {
                "target": "NSIS",
                "arch": [
                    "x64"
                ]
            },
            "icon": "build/favicon-256.ico"
        },
        "msi": {
            "oneClick": false,
            "shortcutName": "ABC.AI"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "oneClick": false,
            "shortcutName": "ABC.AI",
            "installerIcon": "build/favicon-256.ico",
            "installerHeaderIcon": "build/favicon-256.ico",
            "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
        },
        "files": [
            "**/*",
        ],
        "extraFiles": [
            "projects",
            "verify.dll",
            "omodel",
            "f_g"
        ]
    },

I try to change build configuration in different ways but it was corrupting the exe file as well, so reverted back to above configuration. I think i have some issue in build configuration,and would need help on it.
Thankyou
